# Android Live Wallpaper image(video) sequence works...preferences / setting not work (crash app!)

Tags: android, settings, live, preferences, wallpaper

What is wrong with my coding clicking settings will crash app.
I cant read default settings values from prefs.xml

image sequence working like i want and now it's
moving right to left while images continue change (like a video)

someone genious see any problems ? :)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mywallpaper"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />


<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyWallpaperService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" >

        </meta-data>
    </service>
    <activity

        android:label="myPrefs"
        android:name="com.example.mywallpaper.Prefs"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
       android:enabled="true"

        android:exported="true">
         <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
         </intent-filter>

    </activity>     
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

wallpaper.xml

```
<wallpaper
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:name="something"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:description="@string/app_name"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.mywallpaper.Prefs">
</wallpaper>
```

prefs.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="Title Preference"
android:key="myPrefs">
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Touch"
    android:key="touch"
android:summary="Touch enable"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    />
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Speed"
    android:key="speed"
    android:summary="Animation speed"
    android:defaultValue="500"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Prefs.java

```
package com.example.mywallpaper;


import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity
implements
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(MyWallpaperService.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

 getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); 
}

@Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  super.onDestroy();
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
    String key) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

MyWallpaperService.java

```
package com.example.mywallpaper;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "myPrefs";
//drawable image array
int[] myImageList = new int[]{
        R.drawable.bg,
        R.drawable.bg1,
        R.drawable.bg2,
        R.drawable.bg3,
        R.drawable.bg4,
        R.drawable.bg5,
        R.drawable.bg6,
        R.drawable.bg7,
        R.drawable.bg8,
        R.drawable.bg9,
        R.drawable.bg10,
        R.drawable.bg11,
        R.drawable.bg12,
        R.drawable.bg13,
        R.drawable.bg14,
        R.drawable.bg15,
        R.drawable.bg16
        };

public boolean runUp = true;
public boolean touchEnabled = true;
public int mSpeed = 100;
public int bgNumber = 0;
public int bgFrame = 0;
public int bgFrameMax = 20;

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new WallpaperEngine();
    }

private class WallpaperEngine extends Engine
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private boolean mVisible = false;
    private Bitmap backgroundImage;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable mUpdateDisplay = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            draw();
            }
        };

    private void draw() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {

                //paint black
                Paint p = new Paint();
                p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                c.drawRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), p);

                drawBG(c);

                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
        if (mVisible) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateDisplay, mSpeed);
            }



        }



    WallpaperEngine() {
        mPrefs = MyWallpaperService.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPrefs, null);
        }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //super.onTouchEvent(event);
        if(touchEnabled){
            bgNumber = 0;
            }
        }

    public void drawBG(Canvas c){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        Resources res = getResources();
        backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,myImageList[bgNumber], options);

        //move looping imagas (video) right to left
        int CH = c.getHeight();
        int CW = c.getWidth();
        double BH = backgroundImage.getHeight();
        double BW = backgroundImage.getWidth();
        double hScale = (BH/BW);
        int bgSlideX = (CW/bgFrameMax);         
        int wallPH = (int) (CW*hScale);
        int wLeft = 0+(CW-(bgSlideX*bgFrame));
        int wTop = (int) ((CH/2)-(BH/2));
        int wRight = CW+(CW-(bgSlideX*bgFrame));
        int wBottom = wTop+wallPH;

        Rect dest = new Rect(wLeft, wTop, wRight, wBottom);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        c.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, null, dest, paint);


        bgFrame+=1;
        if (bgFrame == bgFrameMax*2){
            bgFrame = 0;
        }

        //Loop images up and down
        if (runUp = true){
            bgNumber += 1;
            if (bgNumber == myImageList.length){
                bgNumber=0;
                runUp = false;
                }
            }
        else if(runUp = false){
            bgNumber -= 1;
            if (bgNumber == 0){
                bgNumber+=1;
                runUp = true;
                }
            }



        backgroundImage.recycle();
        }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        mVisible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            draw();
            }
        else {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
            }
        }



    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        draw();
        }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        mVisible = false;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mVisible = false;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
        }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        mSpeed = Integer.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString("speed", "5000"));
        //sharedPreferences.getInt("speed", 100);
        touchEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("touch", true);
        //mHandler.post(mUpdateDisplay);
        }
    }
public void onPause(){
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted I can already see that you never closed the  tag in your prefs.xml. That would cause a problem. You need to add a  at the end of your prefs.xml to close it.

Comment: Thx for quick respont it was only error on posting closing tag was there :)

Comment: Finally i got preference activity work YIPEE i change android:permission="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"
to android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" from AndroidManifest like i havent try it before so manytimes